# Простенькое клиент-серверное приложение, нужно немного подправить

Tags: python, сокет, инспекция-кода

Мне были поставлены задачи:

1. Реализовать клиент-серверное приложение.
2. Реализовать постоянный сервер (`while True`)
3. Реализовать свой модуль с функциями `readMsg` и `sendMsg`

Вот мой код:

client.py

```
import socket
from modSC import sendMsg

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 1234))
sendMsg(sock)
sock.close()
```

server.py

```
import socket
from modSC import readMsg

sizePack = 5

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 1234))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()
readMsg(conn, sizePack)
```

ModSC.py

```
def sendMsg(sock):
    while True:
        msgData = input()

        msg = msgData.encode()
        msgLen = '%10s' % len(msg)

        sock.send(msgLen.encode())
        sock.send(msg)
        if msgData == '':
            break

def readMsg(conn, sizePack):
    while True:
        sizeMsg = int(conn.recv(10).decode())
        msg = ''

        if sizeMsg == 0:
            break

        else:
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(sizePack).decode()
                sizeMsg -= sizePack
                msg += data

                if sizeMsg - sizePack <= 0:
                    data = conn.recv(sizeMsg).decode()
                    msg += data
                    break

            print(f'msg = {msg}')
```

Код работает, но поставили низкую оценку. Думаю, что основная претензия к двойному `while True` в `readMsg()` . Можно ли переписать как-то более элегантно, ничего не испортив?

Comment: А что длинну текстом отправляешь? Можно байтам

Comment: Да и сервер не вечный)

Comment: да это не так важно, основная претензия к двойному while True в readMsg(), насколько я понял

Comment: А мне кадется к невыполненному пункту 2

Comment: соглашусь. но я в творческом тупике, не могу догадаться как это написать этот код ...

Comment: пол дня уже над ним сижу

Comment: всего полдня) тут минимум надо добавить while true для sock.acept

Comment: Потом разобраться с брейком в конце. Он тут неправильно сделан

Comment: кто-нибудь сможет помочь? я не справлюсь